# solvePNP for planar triangle

Tags: c++, opencv, pose-estimation, opencv-solvepnp

I have a quite simple task: get Euler angles of a planar triangle.  Pattern looks like [this](https://w86i.imgup.net/2d6a.png)

So, the algorithm:

1) get image from webcam -- done

2) convert to gryascale, filter, etc. -- done

3) get mass centers of all connected components, and filter them -- done. Looks like [this](https://l00i.imgup.net/main7a32.png). Red circles describe mass centers of triangle vertices.

Code is quite simple, but here it is:

```
QMap<int, QVector<double> > massCenters(const cv::Mat& image)
{
    cv::Mat output(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, CV_32S);
    cv::connectedComponents(image, output, 8);

    QMap<int, QVector<double> > result;

    for (int y = 0; y < IMAGE_HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < IMAGE_WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            int label = output.at<int>(y, x);

            if (label)
            {
                QVector<double> vec = result.value(label, QVector<double>());

                if (vec.isEmpty())
                {
                    vec.resize(3);
                    vec.fill(0);
                }

                vec[0] += x;
                vec[1] += y;
                vec[2] += 1;
                result[label] = vec;
            }
         }
    }

    return result;
}
```

4) then I call solvePNP to get rotation & translation vectors

```
 cv::solvePnP(m_origin, m_imagePoints, m_cameraMatrix, m_distMatrix, m_rvec, m_tvec);

 //this code is for drawing rvec & tvec on a screen
 std::vector<cv::Point3f> axis;
 vector<cv::Point2f> axis2D;

 axis.push_back(Point3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
 axis.push_back(Point3f(30.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
 axis.push_back(Point3f(0.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f));
 axis.push_back(Point3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f));

 cv::projectPoints(axis, m_rvec, m_tvec, m_cameraMatrix, m_distMatrix, axis2D);

 cv::line(m_orig, axis2D[0], axis2D[1], cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
 cv::line(m_orig, axis2D[0], axis2D[2], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
 cv::line(m_orig, axis2D[0], axis2D[3], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
```

**m_origin** is declared as `std::vector<cv::Point3f> m_origin;` and filled with values (measured in mm)

```
m_origin.push_back(cv::Point3f( 0.0f,   51.0f, 0.0f));
m_origin.push_back(cv::Point3f(-56.0f, -26.0f, 0.0f));
m_origin.push_back(cv::Point3f( 56.0f, -26.0f, 0.0f));
```

**m_imagePoints** is declared as `std::vector<cv::Point2f> m_imagePoints;` and contains pixel coordinates of mass centers (red circles on the second screen).

And I get quite strange results: from [this](https://n82i.imgup.net/bade261.png) to [that](https://w17i.imgup.net/bad21a4c.png)

What have I tried and it didn't help me:

1) used double and float types in m_cameraMatrix, m_distMatrix, m_rvec, m_tvec

2) rearranged points in m_origin

3) played with solvePnPRansac and it's input parameters

4) played with pnp methods: iterative and epnp

5) useExtrinsicGuess=true -- it helps, but sometimes solution is "stuck" and gives completely wrong values (thousand degrees in rotation vector)

And I have several questions:

1) does order of origin and image points matter? As mentioned [here](https://github.com/pthom/TestSolvePnp), sometime it does, but it was a year ago.

2) can my task be solved in some other way, than using solvePnP?

Thanks. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`solvePnPRansac` is not appropriate in your case as you don't have to deal with outlier data.

My guess is that the issue you observe comes from the pattern you choose:

- it is 3 points
- and you add the centroid of the triangle

But in my opinion it is more or less similar as using only 3 points as the 4th point you add is the barycenter of the triangle and should not give any additional information in the pose estimation problem.

Regarding the pose estimation problem from 3 points (P3P), there are up to four possible solutions and the ambiguity can be removed using a 4th point. Some references about this:

- [3D Pose Estimation by Sebastian Grembowietz](http://home.in.tum.de/~grembowi/ar2004_05/3dPoseEstimation_presentation.pdf)
- [The Perspective View of 3 Points](http://faculty.csuci.edu/william.wolfe/csuci/Articles/PerspectiveView/P3P.ppt)
- [Pose from Point Correspondences P3P](https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-perception/lecture/Hw8T3/pose-from-point-correspondences-p3p)
- [[math] – The P3P (Perspective-Three-Point) Principle](http://iplimage.com/blog/p3p-perspective-point-overview/)

My recommendation is to use a 4-points square shape instead and test to see if you observe the same problem (`P3P` flag should be fine). If yes, there is an issue in the code or in the calibration.

Here a paper I believe is related more or less to the issue: [Why is the Danger Cylinder Dangerous in the P3P Problem?](http://nlpr-web.ia.ac.cn/2006papers/gnkw/nk1.pdf). The figure in case the link becomes unavailable:

[image: Danger cylinder]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, yes, you were right, because my problem was solved, when I added one more point. 
One hint more: with CV_P3P I've got strange outlines in first chain of rotation vector, all other angles looked good. Solved it with CV_EPNP.